# mediaelement.js caption please

Tags: mediaelement.js, caption

I'm tryig to give a pekk to this html5 player, and more precisely to the caption part.
I'm trying to figure out how to add a few caption to one video. Looking at the demo pack I just constat it simply not works...
the demo file "mediaelementplayer-track.html" displays a CC button and then 3 choices "none" "English" and French" (I added this one).
The html code is :

```
<video width="360" height="203" id="player2" controls="controls">
<source src="../media/echo-hereweare.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="../media/echo-hereweare.webm" type="video/webm">   
<track kind="subtitles" src="../media/mediaelement.srt" srclang="en" /> 
<track kind="subtitles" src="../media/mediaelement-fr.srt" srclang="fr" />
<p>Your browser leaves much to be desired.</p>          
    </video>    

    <script>
    $('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
// auto-select this language (instead of starting with "None")
startLanguage:'en',
// automatically translate into these languages
translations:['es','ar','zh','ru'],
// enable the dropdown list of languages
translationSelector: true
   });
    </script>
```

So..it's supposed to display at least 4 more languages choices.
And There's no way to choose one of the 2 (en, fr) that appears (radio button do not activate, no Firebug console error, nothing).

**edit the caption actually works in IE (!) + Safari PC (did not tried on Mac) BUT NOT IN FF and CHROME (last releases -FF10 ...)**

Can someone lead me to the right way ?
 Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Without .htacess containing the video type, the caption won't work.

So testing the demo pack out from some wamp or equivalent environment, never gave any result.
As far as I test it in a real server environment, with an htacess, caption came right.

Answer (score 2):

We recently learned that the .srt extension needs to be added as a MIME type to the server. If you can't update your MIME type, since an .srt is just a text file it also works fine if you change the extension of the caption file to .txt and update the link that points to it.